# IllegalStateException: Fragment already added not caught with try-catch

Tags: android, android-fragments, illegalstateexception

So I have this wonderful function:

```
public static MenuPictureFragment newMenuPictureFragment(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity, String userIdParam, int containerId){
    MenuPictureFragment menuPictureFragment = (MenuPictureFragment) fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentActivity.getString(R.string.fragment_tag_menu_picture_fragment));

    try {
        if(menuPictureFragment == null) {
            menuPictureFragment = MenuPictureFragment.newInstance(userIdParam);
        } 
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(containerId, menuPictureFragment, fragmentActivity.getString(R.string.fragment_tag_menu_picture_fragment));
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } catch (RuntimeException re){
        //intentionelly empty
    }

    return menuPictureFragment;
}
```

`menuPictureFragment`is a fragment inside a fragement, if I navigate away from the parent fragment, at some point the app crashes with a `IllegalStateException: Fragment already added`message.

Shouldn't that Exception been caught? Adding `!menuPictureFragment.isAdded()` doesn't help either.

If I replace `fragmentTransaction.add` with `fragmentTransaction.replace` the exception disappears, but the `menuPictureFragment` is only present in the beginning, after circling back (when before the Exception was thrown) the fragment is not shown anymore.

What the hell is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was: you need to use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()` if it's a nested fragment / if you add the fragment to a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

the actual problem most likely is:

that tag `R.string.fragment_tag_menu_picture_fragment` might not have been applied -

and so it will always return `null` (which can be understood as "fragment tag not found").

and then it subsequently will attempt to add that `MenuPictureFragment` twice -

which will throw that uncaught `IllegalStateException`. For example:

```
String tag = fragmentActivity.getString(R.string.fragment_tag_menu_picture_fragment);
menuPictureFragment = MenuPictureFragment.newInstance(userIdParam);
menuPictureFragment.setTag(tag);
```

or pass the desired `String tag` into some method `.newInstance(String userId, String tag)` and let the `Fragment` set it's own tag.

Comment: I already checked that, `fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentActivity.getString(R.string.fragment_tag_menu_picture_fragment));` return the right value.

Comment: also setTag doesnt exist